# How to get the last updated HTML content by using a webview?

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I have one problem, i know how to get HTML source code in webview and have a lot of way to get it. But this is what i met:
For an example, I can get the html source of this website using:

`web.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');")`

But it just give me a first source code HTML, if this website was change some element of html or content will change in some seconds, i can't get it. So how to get the lastest html in webview? I was using The Button, i wait when the website was change content, i click Button to get HTML but still the same as first. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using javascript to get the html code,
then i think you can detect html changes **still using javascript**.

you can try using MutationObserver javascript object, https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
            //RELOAD YOUR WEBVIEW HERE
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
            //RELOAD YOUR WEBVIEW AND HERE
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```